# Send JWT from AngularJS to Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

An AngularJS app needs to exchange a JWT with the Node.js instance that serves it.  The Node.js instance has a `/user` route which returns a JWT to the Angular client.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that 1.) The AngularJS app can send the JWT back to the Node.js instance's `/user` route, and 2.) the Node.js code can isolate the JWT as a variable for processing?**

The current AngularJS code for calling the backend `/user` route is:

```
$http.get('user').then(function(response) {
        console.log('response is: ');
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.token === 'anonymous') {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        } else {
            $rootScope.userJWT = response.data.token; 
            var payload = $rootScope.userJWT.split('.')[1];
            payload = $window.atob(payload);
            payload = JSON.parse(payload);
            self.name = payload.name;
            self.authorities = payload.authorities;
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        }
    }, function() {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    });
```

And the Node.js code for the backend `/user` route is:

```
app.get('/user**', function(req, res) {
    console.log("You Hit The User Route TOP");
    //How do we get the JWT from req?
    var user = getUserName(theJwt);
    var token = getToken(user);
    var jwtJSON = getUser(token);
    if( (jwtJSON["token"] == 'error') || jwtJSON["token"] == 'anonymous' ) {
        res.sendStatus(500);  // Return back that an error occurred
    } else {
        res.json(jwtJSON);
    }
    console.log("You Hit The User Route BOTTOM");
});
```

Note, the Node.js instance includes `var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');`, and one of the processing methods will decode the JWT using `var decoded = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});`, as per [the `jsonwebtoken` API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken).

Comment: This github repo for Satellizer has a complete example:

https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples

Comment: @TaylorAckley  I want to use the `jsonwebtoken` api.  I also want to keep this extremely simple so that I can build up my own app from basics.  The answer is probably as simple as how to add an `Authorization header` to the AngularJS `get('/user')` and then how to isolate that `Authorization header` in the Node.js `/user` route in the small code snippets in the OP above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using JWT there is no required way to communicate the token.

The most common way is to place the token into an HTTP Header.

On the AngularJS side you would make an HTTP request with an extra header (e.g. X-Auth-Token) which contains the JWT.

Example of AngularJS side:

```
var config = {
    headers: {
        "X-Auth-Token": $rootScope.userJWT
    }
}
$http.get('routeThatNeedsJWT', config).then(function(response) { ... });
```

On the Node.js side you would get the contents of the header and process it using the jsonwebtoken library.

Example of Node.js side:

```
app.get('/routeThatNeedsJWT', function(req, res) {
    var rawTokenFromHeader = req.get('X-Auth-Token'); // Get JWT from header
    try {
        var jwtJSON = jwt.verify(token, 'secret'); // Verify and decode JWT
        res.json(jwtJSON);
    } catch (err) {
        res.sendStatus(500);  // Return back that an error occurred
    }
});
```

Helpful links:

[Express 4.x getting header value](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get)

[jsonwebtoken library verify token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback)